# I keep getting EADDRINUSE when deploying a simple node server

Tags: linux, node.js

okay this is really strange , i am getting EADDRINUSE when implementing a simple server ,

1. i have changed the ports
2. looked for the already running node js process
3. tried using killall -9 node with root
4. looking for process hoarding the port through sudo netstat -alpn |grep  node

   ```
   var http= require('http');


   var server=http.createServer(function(request,response){
       response.end("kameha kameha....");
   }).listen("162.x.x.38",8010);
   process.stdin.resume();
   process.on('uncaughtException',function(err){
   console.log("closing due to uncaught exception:"+err.message+"     "+err.data);
       server.close();
       process.exit(1);
   });
    process.on('exit',function(){
       console.log("exiting the program");
        server.close();
        process.exit(0);
   });
   process.on('SIGINT', function(){
       console.log("caught cntrl +c closing the program and performing        cleanups");
      server.close();
       process.exit(0);
   });
   ```

still no help , i am running centos 6.7 on a vps hosted by bluehost , so let me sum is down, there is no node process running , no prcocess is hoarding the port

strangely enough when i put my host as localhost it starts working but still i am unable to connect it via wget

wget localhost:8010
--2015-05-22 15:19:15--  http://localhost:8010/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:8010... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8010... failed: Connection refused.

when running as local host netstat gives the following :

sudo netstat -alp |grep  node
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     453187 23439/node          localhost

protocol as stated by netstat command is unix instead of tcp ,though i dont have much experience with linux so ....but its strange because above code is running fine in windows , but i dont know what is happening here ..help please !!

Comment: `/etc/services` says that 1080 is for a socks proxy server. Do you have anything like that running, by chance?  Also why are you connecting to 8010 with wget and using port 1080 in the node code?

Comment: nopes and i am sorry will fix that in post but , copied the results from many ports i was trying and i tried other ports to , but still getting the same error

Comment: try removing address from `listen("162.x.x.38",8010);`

Comment: Perhaps your example post doesn't really need `url`, `data`, or `querystring` if other people are going to test it.

Comment: It works here with just `listen(1080)` and no IP.

Comment: removing the url, data, and querystring ,i was extending the code but was stuck in basic function  and i checked to it works without address , but why :\ , though it is still a issue as i need to expose this a service , any ideas how to get it working via a external interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for [http.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) were backwards.

From the node.js docs:

> server.listen(port[, hostname][, backlog][, callback])# Begin
>   accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the
>   hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to
>   any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).

The correct call, from the docs link above, is as follows:

Simple, works on any address for the host

```
var server=http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.end("kameha kameha....");
  }).listen(8010);
```

Bind to localhost only

```
var server=http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.end("kameha kameha....");
  }).listen(8010, "127.0.0.1");
```

Bind to 1.2.3.4 is similar

```
var server=http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.end("kameha kameha....");
  }).listen(8010, "1.2.3.4");
```

Comment: haha i was stuck for hours with this stupid thing , i was working with node 0.10.2 which was pre installed and was performing var server=http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.end("kameha kameha....");
  }).listen({host:"localhost",port:1080}); but there was a bug so changed to the above code but did not look for the order .....my bad thanks it helped , it was a stupid but a frustrating mistake :)